# Change -Xmx and Xms settings for EAP on Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm trying to change the default settings for Openshift EAP images (by default the container starts the JVM with -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m).
I've tried adding the settings to JAVA_OPTS_APPEND, however it is not effective. I can see it's being appended at the end of the JAVA_OPTS, but inspecting the JVM process, I can see that defaults are still being used.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the JVM resource limits through the JAVA_OPTS_APPEND won't work. You have to set the Resource Limits to the Container. For example, settings the Resource limits to 1GB, will allow a portion of that to be used for the application server mx and ms limits (typically half of the Resource limits for the Container as you need to dedicate Resource Limits also to the OS)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the container heap ratio using the variable `CONTAINER_HEAP_PERCENT` . Per default, the value is 0.50, meaning the heap is set to the half of the memory resource limit as said by Francesco.